# How to export my Android Studio project as an APK file?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I need to export my Android Studio project as an APK for a college project. What is the correct procedure to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You build it, and it creates an apk in the build/outputs/apk folder.

Comment: Found the APK. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio in the Build Menu there is an option to build apk. you will have to specify if it is to debug or production ready. Make a developer key. Once all of that is set up you let it run and it makes the apk file for you. I can remember exactly where it outputs the file  but I want to say that it pops up a dialog or lets you choose the location the apk is put.